# Ubuntu 17.10.1 not booting after unlocking download

Tags: boot

I installed ubuntu 17.10.1 from live usb   but in boot device option (f9)
Ubuntu bootloader is not showed (grub) i cannot boot into ubuntu

Comment: You should provide more information. Do you receive any error messages?

Comment: Grub goes in mimal mode when booted